# Getting errors when installing second instance on Oracle 10g on the database machine (server)?

Tags: database, oracle10g, multiple-instances

The scenario is like this; we have a database server with **Oracle 10g** installed, with an instance already in use, lets call this `Instance1` (with the same `SID`). Now, we want to have a second instance on the same server, with `SID` i.e. `Instance2`. I try to use the DCA (**Database Configuration Assistant**), but keeps getting errors at the end of the creation (normally around 85%).

Error message goes like this:

```
Enterprise manager configruration failed due to the followin error - 
Error starting Database Control Refer to the log file at C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db-1\cftoollogs\dbca\Instance2\emConfig.log for more details. You can retry configuring this database with Enterprise Manager later my manually running C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin\emca script
```

I'm getting the feeling that I need to do this commandline, and maybe change some config files. Could anyone please give med some pointers, or any good guide I can follow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe providing the errors when asking how to fix them would be useful?